# ASP.NET Core Authenticating Clients (Console/WPF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I've searched far and wide for a working (simple) solution to Authentication in asp.net core which is up to date. I am sorry if I have missed it and if someone has already provided the solution, but here comes the question:

I've buil an ASP.NET Core MVC/API solution with Identity/EF CookieAuthentication. With this i can log in/out in my MVC and set claims/roles to the User.

I have a WPF client whom I'd like to authenticate as well and connect to my API. So far I have attempted to use HttpClient to sign in the same way as I do in ASP.NET - SignInManager with credentials. But how do i persist this session/cookie/token to the wpf client so that future HttpRequests will be authenticated through the built in Identity?

Comment: hi, sorry to just post a link, but I really do think this might help you https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop it might only cover ASP.NET though, which I don't think is quite what your're after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deriving your own `WebClient`

```
public class MyClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("request == null");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.CookieContainer = this._container;

        ... // Add Required Cookies Here?
        Uri target = new Uri("http://example.com");
        this._container.Add(new Cookie("_spc", "aefec0ba-dc10-23e5-46f1-6b6e50c8837e") { Domain = target.Host }); 

        return request;
    }
}
```